# How to get data from such blob:http:// url in golang?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, blob

I have an api written in go, which takes the input in form of blob file, actually a blob url from frontend , When the file gets uploaded to s3 it makes an empty image.

**My Go S3 Code looks like**

```
bucket := os.Getenv(infrastructure.FilesBucketName)
if err := s3.PutS3Object(
    bucket,
    "testimage_12344589.jpeg",
    []byte("blob:http://localhost:3001/65e1e5ae-419e-44db-b651-a37c388a0ccb"),
    aws.String("image/jpeg")); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

What is the best way to fix this issue ?
I have also tried approaches like converting url to string etc, but nothing worked.

Comment: 2 things: 
1) which package are you using? 
2) http://localhost smells a bit.

what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: []byte("blob:http://localhost:3001/65e1e5ae-419e-44db-b651-a37c388a0ccb") is behaving as []byte("string) .It will convert the url to byte not the contents of that url .If you are getting the image from that place .

Comment: Are you trying to use a Javascript Blob object outside of a browser?  That won't work, the URL only makes sense within that browser session.

Comment: @MassimoCosta - I am using the package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3 . I am getting this blob url from a frontend application implementing graphQL  as a input and I have to convert this into image and upload to s3 bucket.

Comment: @NehaAgrawal - Yes I tried to get the image content from this url in order to send to S3 , but could not found the accurate way to do with such kind of url.

Comment: @AnonCoward-  I have just posted here what frontend application ( written into React js ) is passing to this API. In actual I am not using blob object directly outside the browser.

Comment: "I am not using blob object directly outside the browser" What?  You're using right here in code outside of the browser trying to upload it to S3.  It only makes sense inside of the browser, it won't do anything outside of the session of the browser.